# Get all property names from a custom tag

Tags: jsp, taglib

I have this two custom tags in my JSP -  `gf`,`ctag` :

```
<gf:writeToolTip labelSet="None">
    <ctag:property property="name" />
</gf:writeToolTip>
```

This code works fine and puts in a tooltip the value of property `name`.

What I need to do is to get the value of another property, but I don't know its name and I don't have access to the backend code to see the `ctag` definition. How to see every name of each property from `ctag` tag?

Comment: How Struts is related? And which Struts?

Comment: The application is build with Struts 1 I think as I see comments within code back from 2005, but maybe this is not related to my question

Answer (score 1):

JSP compiler using tags according to their DTD or schema definition which is defined by the `taglib` directive. That includes the location of DTD that you can download and examine its source code in xml where all possible attributes are listed.

Comment: I found a `tld` file which is referenced in my `jsp` file, but I see there only some of the proprieties for `<ctag>` tag. Could the other proprieties be defined in some java class??

Comment: yes, they could be added dynamically, you can't know them, it's just a data that you have not access.

Comment: I see, so then I need to look at this class that does the dynamic creation of proprieties and try to add the one I need.

Comment: The class is an implementation of the tag it's using `property` value as a string from JSP and doesn't have any other values.

Comment: So then what would be the approach on finding if the property I want, exists in the dynamic generation?

Comment: You don't have a property, it might be dynamic (from database), you can't get it.

Comment: But where should I look to find the code that goes to the database and retrieve the proprieties, I know that the framework used to do that is `Struts`, but I can't figure out how is this mapping the proprieties to the `jsp` custom tags...

Comment: You can't get properties without source code. It's impossible.

Comment: I got access to some jars where I can see the classes that are imported in the `jsp` file. Should the properties of the ctag that are not in the `tld` file be added from some of the classes's method or how the properies are bound at runtime?

Comment: I don't know what are you asking. May be you ask it in another thread?

Comment: I want to find the code where the `property="name"` on the `ctag` tag is dynamically defined, where should I look for this?? because I need to add some other property to this tag..